# Django collected static files are not accessible by templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I've created a django project with some apps. Initially, I just had a single app and i had static files and templates in it. As my project grew, I added some other apps to the project which they are still accessing the statics files and templates from inside the main app. I wasn't giving much care to this problem until i tried to make a simple production and used `collectstatic` command. Seems i can collect my static files to the `STATIC_ROOT` directory but i can't access them in the templates. Here is my project structure:

```
shop/
-myshop(main app)
--statics
--templates
-(some other apps beside main app)
-shop(directory created by project containing settings.py, manage.py)
```

This is my relevant `settings.py` configurations:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'myshop/static',
]
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
```

After running `collectstatic` django creates the `static` directory in root of project but when i remove or rename the `myshop/static` i get static files 404 in `runserver`.
I dont know how to check `{% load static %}` resulting path in runtime to put more information here. Is there any debug routine to understand what's django backend doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   BASE_DIR / "static",
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR.parent / "static_cdn"
```

`$ python manage.py collectstatic` This command  will copy all files from your static folders into the STATIC_ROOT directory.

You must write the names of the static folder and the static root folder diffrent.

To learn more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Comment: you can remove .parent at BASE_DIRS if you want your static root should be inside the you project.

Comment: what's this going to do? I mean should i run collect statics after these changes? Beside that my`STATICFILES_DIRS`' is not in BASE_DIR / "static"

Comment: In my case they are actually different! One is `BASE / static` for collected static file. The other is `BASE / myshop / static` from which static files are collected with collectstatic.

Comment: I know the two are different but the collectist finds the static folder and stores it in the static root. But you have named both the static route and the static same, due to that you may have also made an error, just change and try